# Angular 2 - Using Observables in a component to emit values to other components

Tags: asynchronous, angular, reactive-programming, observable

I am wondering if it is possible to use Observables in components, and which other components can subscribe to?

**BugListComponent**
- component is injected in the boot.ts file where I load all my services (where *boostrap* is located)

```
import {Subject, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/Rx';

viewBugList$: Subject<boolean>;

constructor() { 
    this.viewBugList$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
}

// Called from template, sends in 'true'
private enableIEview(enable: boolean) {   
    if(enable) {
        this.viewBugList$.next(true);
    }
}
```

**BugListContainerComponent**

```
import {BugListComponent} from '../buglist/bug-list.component';

initView: boolean;

constructor(private _bugListComp: BugListComponent) {
    this.initView = false;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this._bugListComp.viewBugList$.subscribe(e => {
        if(e != null) {
            this.initView = e;
        }
    });
}
```

So, far the 'subscribe' in the BugListContainerComponent does not seem to be affected when the .next is called from the BugListComponent.

Below is an overview image:
[image: The architecture]

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it's not possible. You can only trigger events to the parent component of a component using the `EventEmitter` class defined as `@Ouput` of the child component.

For other components, you need to define the `Observable` within a shared service. The component can inject this service and subscribe on the observable. The other component can also inject the service and trigger the event.

It's almost the same code as yours but in a service service.

- **Shared service**

  ```
  export class SharedService {
    constructor() { 
      this.viewBugList$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    }

    enableView() {
      this.viewBugList$.next(true);
    }
  }
  ```
- **Define the service when bootstrapping**

  ```
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedService ]);
  ```
- **BugListContainerComponent**

  ```
  constructor(private service: SharedService) {
    this.initView = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.viewBugList$.subscribe(e => {
      if(e != null) {
        this.initView = e;
      }
    });
  }
  ```
- **BugListComponent**

  ```
  viewBugList$: Subject<boolean>;

  constructor(private service:SharedService) { 
    this.viewBugList$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  }

  // Called from template, sends in 'true'
  private enableIEview(enable: boolean) {   
    if(enable) {
      this.service.viewBugList$.next(true);
    }
  }
  ```

This shared service must be defined when bootstrapping your application in order to have a single instance for the whole application.

Comment: Aha, so I feared. So it is possible to pass an `@output` from BugListComp to AppComp, via SidebarComp? Then `@input` down from AppCom to BugListContainerComp via MainContainerComp?

Then probably it is easier to just create a service for it ^^

Thank you for your fast answer btw!

Comment: Yes this could be possible but events don't bubble. So you need to define them at each level. So this would be painful... Yes creating a service is definitely easier ;-)

Comment: Ok, thanks! For these kinds of services, which will be very small and only emit  eg. true/false, would it be feasible to collect these in one service, if there will be several similar situations like this? Or have one service for each of them?

Comment: Yes, make sense. In fact, you're free to organize this like your want ;-) Only one service with several properties, several ones, ... It's up to you

Comment: i have a question...this shareService in angular 2 is like websocket?i meaning is alive?or we should trigger an event thak send a value?
i have an idea in my mind...i want create a service and watch a property and when change to true or false...send value...this shareService is like my mind ?!how to  create a service like this?

Answer (score 2):

***BugListComponent***

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Output,EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {sharedService} from './sharedService';


constructor(private ss:sharedService) { 

}

private enableIEview(enable: boolean) {   
    if(enable) {
        this.ss.setEventEmitter(enable);
    }
}
```

***sharedService.ts***

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Output,EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

export class sharedService {

@Output() viewBugList$:EventEmitter<boolean>=new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { 

  }

  setEventEmitter(enable:boolean) {
    //this.viewBugList$.emit(enable);
      this.viewBugList$.next(enable);
  }

  getEventEmitter()
  {
     return this.viewBugList$;
  }
}
```

***boot.ts***

```
import {sharedService} from './sharedService';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedService ]);
```

***BugListContainerComponent***

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Output,EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {sharedService} from './sharedService';

initView: boolean;

constructor(private ss:shareService) {
    this.initView = false;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.ss.getEventEmitter.subscribe(e => {
        if(e != null) {
            this.initView = e;
        }
    });
}
```