# angular2- how to communicate between two separate components?

Tags: events, typescript, angular, eventemitter

I am working on this angular2 project.
I have 2 components i.e. `WorkspacesComponent & PagesComponent`.

in database,each workspace contains number of pages. 
I have written below code to populate list of workspaces in workspacesComponent & list of pages in PagesComponent.

**getting workspaces from database**

```
 this.workspaceService.getAllWorkspaces(this.baseUrl)
        .subscribe((workspaces) => {
            this.workspaces = workspaces;
            console.log(this.workspaces);
        }
        );
```

**getting pages from databases**

```
this.pagesService.getAllpages(this.baseUrl)
        .subscribe((pages) => {
            this.pages = pages;
            console.log(this.pages);
        }
        );
```

so far , they are returning me correct data.but I want to implement the functionality where I will be selecting workspace in `workspaceComponent` & all the pages in that workspace only should be listed in `pagesComponent`.

[image: Expected result]

that is, on click of workspace, its index can be passed to below method.

```
getPagesByWorkspaceId(index:string){
    console.log(index);
}
```

and this method will load the list of pages in that workspace accordingly.
the problem is that I am not sure how to call a method in `PagesComponent` from `WorkspacesComponent`

any inputs?

Answer (score 1):

For communication between components that are not in a direct parent-child relationship use a shared service to share data and communicate.

For more info see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 1):

If there is no relation (parent/child) between your two components, you need to leverage a shared service.

See this question for more details:

- [Angular 2 - Using Observables in a component to emit values to other components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283803/angular-2-using-observables-in-a-component-to-emit-values-to-other-components/36283857#36283857)

This link from the angular doc could also help you:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service