# Angular 2 how to pass data between different components

Tags: angular

I have two different components: one is a *login* component and the other is *users* component.

In the login component I am authenticating with `MakeLogin` function and after that getting user details from API and navigating by route to the home page (in the home page the users component is initiated)

The user details that I am getting from the API are saved to an object `UserItem`. This object needs to be alive in the users component and I cant manage to do that

I would like to know what is the best method to get it work

Thanks !

The Login Component :

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{
    token : string;
    loginDetails : LoginItem;
    LoginStatus : boolean;
    error : string;
    private loader = false;
    currentUser : UserItem;

    constructor(private LoginService : LoginService,private router : Router){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.LoginStatus = this.LoginService.CheckLoginStatus();
        if(this.LoginStatus === true){
            this.router.navigate(['']);
        }
    }

    MakeLogin(Email:string,Password:string) {
        this.error = null;
        this.loader = true;
        this.loginDetails = new LoginItem(Email,Password);
        this.LoginService.PostLogin(this.loginDetails).subscribe(data => {
            if(data === true){
                this.token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
                this.UsersService.GetUserDetailsFromDB(this.token).subscribe(data =>{
                    this.currentUser = new  UserItem(data.firstName,data.lastName,data.email,data.id);
                    this.router.navigate([''])
                 });
            }
        }, error =>{
            if(error === 401){
                console.log(error);
                this.loader = false;
                this.error = "Username or Password incorrect";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2- how to communicate between two separate components?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133325/angular2-how-to-communicate-between-two-separate-components)

Answer (score 1):

In your `Users` component you need to have a property defined as `@Input() user: UserItem`. Also, make sure that you import `Input` from `@angular/core`. The HTML view that you use for your users component needs to be able to accept your object of type `UserItem` in order to be able to show it in the component. For example:

**user.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { UserItem } from "../your/location/of/UserItem";

@Component({
   selector: 'user-details',
   templateUrl: 'location/to/your/client/views/user.component.html'
})
export class UserComponent {
    @Input() user: UserItem;
}
```

In your login component, depending where you want to host `user-details`, you need to specify something like: `<user-details [user]="currentUser" />`

The `[user]` part corresponds to the above `@Input() user: UserItem;` property definition. The `currentUser` is what you are getting from the API and what you want to display in the user details.

### Update

According to your comment, the best way for you to achieve what you want is to create a service that would be shared between the two components. Because services are instantiated as singletons, your values will be available between the components.

Comment: thanks but i know this method already
the login and the user component are not connected they have different routers
the login component is not the parent component of users

Comment: Then what seems to be the issue? You question states that you cannot communicate between the components.